# MySQL query getting a string value from query result

Tags: mysql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tb_circulares LEFT JOIN tb_colegios ON tb_circulares.colegio_circular = tb_colegios.id_colegio

    LEFT JOIN tb_circulares_clase ON tb_circulares.codigo_circular = tb_circulares_clase.circular
    LEFT JOIN tb_clases ON tb_circulares_clase.clase = tb_clases.id_clase
    WHERE colegio_circular = 17
```

The query output shows three rows.

One of the row columns is the value for the field tb_circular_clase.nombre_clase

I would like to get a string containing the three resulting values for tb_circular_clase.nombre_clase.

For example:

```
row1-> nombre_clase = "1º primaria"

row2-> nombre_clase = "3ª secundaria"

row3-> nombre_clase = "4º primaria"
```

Is it possible to get a resulting query field with the final value?

```
`resultado = "1º primaria - 3ª secundaria - 4º primaria"
```

Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry,I appreciate your proposal, but I am not a SQL expert. I only use MySQL in a basic approach. I guess the proposed link is far beyond my needs.

Comment: I guess the proposed link is EXACTLY what you need. The accepted answer was written with you in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're after `group_concat()`, which is an aggregation function concatenating all values of a group.

```
SELECT group_concat(nombre SEPARATOR ' - ') resultado
       FROM tb_circulares
            LEFT JOIN tb_colegios
                      ON tb_circulares.colegio_circular = tb_colegios.id_colegio
            LEFT JOIN tb_circulares_clase
                      ON tb_circulares.codigo_circular = tb_circulares_clase.circular
            LEFT JOIN tb_clases
                      ON tb_circulares_clase.clase = tb_clases.id_clase
       WHERE colegio_circular = 17;
```